# Unable to show in frontend images uploaded via Django REST framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-media

I'm trying to create Django REST app, however I cannot manage to allow the url of the image to be accessible.

I managed to get the upload done, however when I have the URL there is no way to access the photo from browser. I stored them in folder profile_pictures and I was thinking of loading the image from `localhost:8000/profile_pictures/image_name.jpg` but I'm not sure how to setup this, as I tried linking static files to the urls but nothing seems to work.

settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")
MEDIA_URL = '/profile_pictures/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,"profile_pictures")
```

urls.py

```
if settings.DEBUG: 
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

However, it says that the static name is not defined even tho I import it using:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
```

I upload the images with Simple REST API which I only created for testing:

```
class UploadPictureAPI(generics.GenericAPIView):
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)

    def post(self, request):
        x = AdditionalUser(user=request.user, profile_picture=request.data['profile_picture'])
        x.save()
        print(x)
        return Response({"message": "uploaded"})
```

and I store them in a database as such:

```
class AdditionalUser(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    profile_picture = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_pictures')
    user_bio = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    user_instagram = models.CharField(max_length=300)
```

They get uploaded to the DataBase and in the folder, but I cannot get access to them from the url(which I get as profile_picture.url) of the database, it says page not found

Comment: Please add settings.py and elaborate what you mean by `upload done`. Do you upload these files via REST API?

Comment: I upload them by REST API and I tested it with postman, they arrive in the folder, however I cannot figure a way to make them hosted on the localhost to be able to send them as url to separate frontend app. I’m not sure what to put in the settings, I tried some things from the django website but were giving a lot of errors and not working

Comment: So please show your code and the errors you get.

Comment: I'm very sorry about that, I just added code about what I tried

Comment: Are these image files supposed to be `static` or `media`? You say `static` but use `MEDIA_URL`. Please show a template code which references these images and the method which handles file upload. And please add **error messages** or **http statuses** retrieved on image url access attempt.

Comment: The images are supposed to be uploaded as profile pictures from REST API, I'm not sure if this is supposed to be media or static, it throws Name Error saying that static is not defined

Comment: I added the model I use and the test API I created

Comment: If uploaded by users and saved to model's `ImageField` then **media** files. Still no template code shown.

Comment: I don't have any templates, I only use Django for backend API calls and I have separate front-end app

Comment: So urls don't work or you don't know how to return these urls to frontend? Please bring more clarity to the original post. Still zero code attempting to access these images shown, zero specific error messages. What "does not work", how?

Comment: I don't know how to make the pictures stored in the folder available as source on the url of the django backend so I can send the URL of these images with REST API and show them on the frontend. I tried accessing this pictures from the browser (with url I got from the database), however I couldn't do it, I'm not sure what else should I try

Comment: The problem was that Django is not very friendly if you are not having templates, I was only using it for REST APIs, and when I added template it started working.